# How to check array value in dyamically in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Consider selected array have two values

```
$scope.selected = ["Show Activated","Show InActivated"]
```

This below source code is working fine because here i am checking the value manually for example:
i am checking whether  `Show Activated` or  `Show InActivated`  then i am assign `isActive` value `true` or `false`

My requirement is dynamically i have to do this. if it is `Show Activated` assign `isActive` value is `True`.
Please check [this plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHyT7fH58YrFXgtXn2m2?p=preview)...

This below source code in plunker  won't work because it's my real code for understanding purpose added in that link. But selection part working fine.

```
 // Object Filteration 
     $scope.objectFilterSubmit = function () {  
        if($scope.selected.length>1) {
             $scope.IsActive = "";
             $scope.selectedObjectDatas = $scope.getCustomObjectsBasedOnObjectTypeSelection($scope.IsActive);
             clearPartialElement();
             $scope.objectCreationPage();
        } else {
            angular.forEach($scope.selected, function(value,key){
                if(angular.equals(value, "Show Activated")) {   
                   $scope.IsActive = "true";   
                   $scope.selectedObjectDatas = $scope.getCustomObjectsBasedOnObjectTypeSelection($scope.IsActive);
                   clearPartialElement();
                   $scope.objectCreationPage();  
                }   
                else if(angular.equals(value, "Show InActivated")) {    
                     $scope.IsActive = "false";              
                     $scope.selectedObjectDatas = $scope.getCustomObjectsBasedOnObjectTypeSelection($scope.IsActive);
                     clearPartialElement();
                     $scope.objectCreationPage();   
                }
                else {
                     $scope.IsActive = "";
                     $scope.selectedObjectDatas = $scope.getCustomObjectsBasedOnObjectTypeSelection($scope.IsActive);
                     clearPartialElement();
                     $scope.objectCreationPage();
                }
            });
       }
      };
```

Please anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Just so I'm clear... you want a variable isActive to be true when the "Show Activated" is clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by this statement "My requirement is dynamically i have to do this". You are already doing it dynamically. Also the logic looks incorrect because you are overwriting the same variable "$scope.IsActive"  in a loop.

Comment: @DWDuck   yes i want to set variable isActive is true. but not at the time clicking , after click is completed. I have to click ok button my page. That time in that array may have one or more values. Using that array i have to set the isActive value.

Comment: @Rudra - Sorry. May be i mentioned wrong words. Please check my comments, i hope you will get clear now. If not please let me know. I will explain in detaily.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for... you can put a $watch on the isClicked value of "Show Activated"... Changed in the plunker below..

http://plnkr.co/edit/axJ5X9bTpMOTkNVS9oqk?p=preview

A few changes from yours.  First binding an isActive variable to the directive:

```
<so-table-directive is-active="isActive"></so-table-directive>
```

Then adding a watch in your directive for when that value changes.

```
$scope.$watch('model.objectTypes[0].isChecked', function(val) {
  $scope.isActive = val;
})
```

Is this what you mean?

If you need to watch both checkboxes, use $watchGroup (in angular 1.3 or later):

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['model.objectTypes[0].isChecked', 'model.objectTypes[1].isChecked'], function(val) {
  if(val[0] && val[1]) {
    $scope.isActive="Show All";
  } else if(val[0]) {
    $scope.isActive=true;
  } else {
    $scope.isActive=false;
  }
})
```

Comment: Not exactly matching. but i'm trying using your code. If "Show All" clicked means i have to set the isActive value empty " " or "Show All" as value. but currently it's showing true if i click show all.

Comment: Can you use a more recent angular, like 1.3 or later?  Then you could use $watchGroup to watch all of them....

Comment: I changed the answer and plunker to change results if both are clicked.  You would need to use a more recent angular so $watchGroup is available.